# Get input data of Suggest Box in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I have Suggest Box widget and I need to make suggestions based on several fields. App Maker allows only use 1 field for suggestions, so I need to implement custom "suggest" function.

I am binding to `onInputChange(widget, event)` to get current input, but there is no input data.

How can I retreive user's input in suggest box widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access Suggest Box widget input using `event.srcElement.value`:

```
function suggestBoxInputChange(widget, event)
{
  console.log(event.srcElement.value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new query builder data source base on your data source with something like

```
Column1 startsWith? :search or Column2 startsWith? :search or Column3 startsWith? 
:search
```

Then add a standard text box with the oninputchange event something like

```
widget.datasource.query.parameters.search = widget.value;
widget.datasource.load();
```

even change the textbox to searchbarlight up in the top right